# Trouble importing email template with package.xml

Tags: email-template, force.com, eclipse, package.xml

For my Eclipse Force.com project, I'm trying to import an Email Template. know that EmailTemplate doesn't accept wildcards in its package.xml formatting, but even when I name the individual template and refresh from my org's server, I'm still ending up with a timeout and an empty src folder. Does this line of xml that I placed in package.xml look correct?

This is what I'm typing after the version tag:

```
<types>
<members>Unique_Name_Of_Template</members>
<name>EmailTemplate</name></types>
```

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be "Folder Name/Template Name", like this:

```
<types>
  <members>Folder_Name/Unique_Name_Of_Template</members>
  <name>EmailTemplate</name>
</types>
```

This is mentioned in [EmailTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_emailtemplate.htm), with a demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MyDBFolder/MyDBName</members>
        <name>Dashboard</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>MyDocumentFolder/MyDocumentName</members>
        <name>Document</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>unfiled$public/MarketingProductInquiryResponse</members>
        <members>unfiled$public/SalesNewCustomerEmail</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>MyReportFolder/MyReportName</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```

The named version without a `/` is a [Folder](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_folder.htm):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Email_Folder_To_Retrieve</members>
        <name>EmailTemplate</name>
    </types>
    <version>41.0</version>
</Package>
```